# How can i validate if the email is already exist in the database without refreshing the php page?

Tags: php, html

As of now I am validating my inputs using this type of approach

```
<form method="post">
<label>Email</label>
<input type="email" name="user_email">
<input type="submit" name="reg">
</form>
if(isset($_POST['reg']){
$result = checkEmail($_POST['email']);
//checkEmail() is my function to check email, if it returns true it has duplicate
if($result){
echo '<p>E-mail already exist!</p>'
else{
//something to do in this..
}
```

I have seen some website after I type the email it automatically updates and i want to learn how to that without using any frameworks since I am just a starter, i just want a simple code. Any suggestions or advice on how to do it? Thank you :)

Comment: is this a good article? http://www.bitrepository.com/a-simple-ajax-username-availability-checker.html

Comment: apart from being 4 years old, it looks ok. it doesn't sanitise the user-name it checks and uses the dated mysql_* functions.

Comment: i see where i can find a good tutorial about jquery validation that has database, i search on this but don't find any http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to use [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) for that.  To use Ajax natively is a lot of work though, you'd have to care for different browsers and a lot of ground work which can be taken care of by using a lightweight javascript libraries like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).  Using jquery together with an excellent plugin like [Validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) you can achieve what you're looking for.  They have a working example of what you're trying to do at [this demo page](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry but I think you'll need to use some AJAX code, [HERE](http://beski.wordpress.com/2009/05/16/check-email-already-exist-ajax-jquery/)
I found a very interesting code.

Comment: the php in the at example is dated, its using the depreciated ereg functions